# Rails - Building Conditions Array for Prepared Statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying build a conditions array to be using in a prepared statement:

```
Cars.find(:all, :conditions=>["color = ? AND doors = ? AND type = ?", "black", "4", "sedan"])
```

I've tried doing the following but getting an error of "ActiveRecord::PreparedStatementInvalid (wrong number of bind variables (4 for 2)":

```
conditions = []
conditions += ["color = ?", "black"]
conditions += ["doors = ?", "4"]
conditions += ["type = ?", "sedan"]

Cars.find(:all, :conditions=>conditions)
```

What is the proper way of building a conditional for prepared statements?

Comment: What version of Rails is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are building a wrong query, since you pass the params to the questionmarks all the way through your statement.

Your resulting query looks something like this:

```
 => ["color = ?", "black", "doors = ?", "4", "type = ?", "sedan"]
```

In order to achieve your desired array, you would have to do something like this.

```
conditions = []
conditions += ["color = ?", "black"]
array = ["doors = ?", "4"]
conditions[0].concat(" AND ")
conditions[0].concat(array[0])
conditions << array[1]
```

If you repeat the last steps, you should get your required result.

Comment: Mandi, thanks for the reply. This method seems to work. But it seems a bit cluttered. I'll likely default to using this method if nothing else works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this easier to do with a hash:

```
conditions = {}
conditions[:color] = "black"
conditions[:doors] = 4
conditions[:type] = "sedan"

Cars.find(:all, :conditions=>conditions)
```

Comment: zetetic, how would I use the hash for situations where I need to query using LIKE or regexp?

Comment: Then you're stuck with passing in a string or an array as shown in Mandi's answer.